# Sci-fi book - pleasure planet with dragons that cried gemstone tears

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I am hoping to find the title and author of a book I read back in my youth (70s). It was a science fiction book that starts out on a pleasure planet and two children find dragon-like creatures that emit tears that turn into gemstones... and I think the premise of the book was how the kids tried to keep outside forces from exploiting them. Has anyone read a book with all of that?

Comment: We're gonna need some more details than that, although it's likely identifiable from the info given, why do you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details.